# Analog of zoom level in react-native-maps?

Tags: leaflet, zoom, react

I am toying with migrating a web-based application to react-native.  The web based application is well developed using leaflet (and react-leaflet).  To show different marker images at different zoom levels, we use the current zoom level of the map:

```js
const getIcon = zoom => {
    if (zoom >= 14) {
        return {
            icon: bigicon,
            anchor: [44, 88],
        };
    }
    if (zoom >= 12) {
        return {
            icon: mediumicon,
            anchor: [22, 44],
        };
    }
    // ...etc.
};
```

Where the `zoom >= X` refers to the zoom level of the map, as is commonly used in most web-based [slippymap tile names](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames#Zoom_levels).

The best platform I've found so far for maps in react-native is [react-native-maps](https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps).  Its management of the map bounds / zoom is very different.  While the [API docs](https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/mapview.md) do seem to allow for things like `minZoomLevel` and `maxZoomLevel`, with those values being the same slippytile zoom levels, I don't see any way to get the current "zoom" of the map.  In leaflet, we can do `map.getZoom()`.  I don't see anything similar in react-native-maps.  Am I missing it?

Rather, we have easy access to what they call the `Region`, which is essentially the latitude and longitude of the center of the map, as well as the `latitudeDelta` and `longitudeDelta` (the height and width of the bounds, in latlng degrees).  So setting up a map looks like this:

```js
 <MapView
      region={{
        latitude: 51,
        longitude: 0,
        latitudeDelta: 1,
        longitudeDelta: 1,
      }}
      onRegionChangeComplete={region => {
        // save region to state to be read elsewhere
      }}
    >
```

As you can see, the `Region` datatype has these 4 values in it.  Not quite so friendly as far as measuring overall zoom, and then picking the correct icon type for the markers.

Is there a way to get the slippymap tile analog of zoom in react-native-maps?

If not, what might be a reasonable formula for transforming a native maps `Region` into a zoom level?

Comment: Just found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46568465/convert-a-region-latitudedelta-longitudedelta-into-an-approximate-zoomlevel...maybe best to close this question